# how do i make a setup.py file for cx_freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I keep trying and nothing I do seems to work. my code is

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Countdown",
    version = "3.1",
    description = "A simple countdown program.",
    executables = [Executable("countdown.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

it will build the executable, but when i run it, i get an error when it comes to my `input()` line and says `lost sys.stdin`
help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Win32GUI` base doesn't use a console, so it doesn't have any sys.stdin to read from.

If you're calling `input()`, you probably want to use the `Console` base for your application.